# How to Change #logo and .mobile_menu_bar_toggle:before elements colour dynamically depending on any other colour behind on a pixel level

Tags: javascript, wordpress, divi

SO... I tried, everything, I am not seemingly knowledgeable enough about this particular Plain JS solution as I thought I was.

I turned to many blogs, sites, AI's and logic, and console logs and tests, to no avail to get what I need.

" How to Change #logo and .mobile_menu_bar_toggle:before elements colour dynamically depending on any other colour behind on a pixel level. "

Whether I skipped best practice, particular methodology or something obscure I haven't learnt yet, I am at a loss :)

1 - This is a wordpress / divi theme site
2 - Its not modified in any way, base implementation.
3 - I can't add changes to it as the deployment needs to stay as low maintenance as possible thus, the attempt in Plain JS OG JS. The only JS that has never caused problems for me due to Libraries

My "solution" thus far below, there are no console errors to report, but also, nothing is happening.

```
// Function to calculate contrast color based on a given RGB color
function calculateContrastColor(rgb) {
  var colors = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
  if (!colors) {
    return 'black'; // Default to black if parsing fails
  }
  var r = parseInt(colors[1]);
  var g = parseInt(colors[2]);
  var b = parseInt(colors[3]);
  var luminance = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b;
  return luminance > 128 ? 'black' : 'white';
}

// Function to update logo/icon colors based on sampled pixel colors
function updateColors() {
  var logo = document.getElementById('logo');
  var menuIcon = document.querySelector('.mobile_menu_bar_toggle');
  
  // Create hidden canvas elements to sample pixel colors
  var logoCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var menuIconCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  logoCanvas.style.display = 'none';
  menuIconCanvas.style.display = 'none';
  
  // Set canvas dimensions to match the logo and menu icon elements
  logoCanvas.width = logo.clientWidth;
  logoCanvas.height = logo.clientHeight;
  menuIconCanvas.width = menuIcon.clientWidth;
  menuIconCanvas.height = menuIcon.clientHeight;
  
  // Append canvases to the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(logoCanvas);
  document.body.appendChild(menuIconCanvas);
  
  // Function to sample pixel color at a specific position on the canvas
  function getPixelColor(canvas, x, y) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var pixel = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    return 'rgb(' + pixel[0] + ', ' + pixel[1] + ', ' + pixel[2] + ')';
  }
  
  // Sample pixel colors below the logo and menu icon
  var logoBelowColor = getPixelColor(logoCanvas, 0, logoCanvas.height - 1);
  var menuIconBelowColor = getPixelColor(menuIconCanvas, 0, menuIconCanvas.height - 1);
  
  // Calculate contrast colors
  var logoContrastColor = calculateContrastColor(logoBelowColor);
  var menuIconContrastColor = calculateContrastColor(menuIconBelowColor);
  
  // Apply the contrast colors
  logo.style.color = logoContrastColor;
  menuIcon.style.color = menuIconContrastColor;
  
  // Remove the canvases from the DOM
  document.body.removeChild(logoCanvas);
  document.body.removeChild(menuIconCanvas);
}

// Function to handle scroll event and update colors using requestAnimationFrame
function handleScroll() {
  requestAnimationFrame(updateColors);
}

// Initialize colors
updateColors();

// Attach the scroll event listener
window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```